# Nested for-loops, iteration, count multiple occurences of an item

Tags: python, loops, nested

Here is a slice of code and at the bottom, in the ' ' 'commented out section' ' ' of the code, there is a line which is surprising to me. Please take a look:

```
#!/path/to/python 
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def frequencer(sliced):    
    podium = []  
    for item in sliced:
        scat = len(sliced)
        print ("le the first scat for the word ' {0} ' is '{1} '.".format(item, scat))
        for indice in range (len(sliced)):
            print("indice = ", indice)
            print("sliced[indice]",sliced[indice])
            if sliced[indice] == item:
                print ("sliced[indice] is equal to ' {0} ', identical to ' {1} ' item.".format(sliced[indice], item))
                scat -= 1
                print("scat is equal to ' {0} '.".format(scat))
        print("scat exdented: ", scat)
        frequence = len(sliced) - scat
        print("frequence: ", frequence)
        podium += [frequence]
        print("podium: ", podium)
    print("podium: ", podium)
    return(max(podium))
print(frequencer( ['Here', 'is', 'a', 'line', 'like', 'sparkling', 'wine', 'Line', 'up', 'now', 'behind', 'the', 'cow']))

'''
le the first scat for the word ' line ' is '13 '.
indice =  0
sliced[indice] Here
indice =  1
sliced[indice] is
indice =  2
sliced[indice] a
indice =  3
sliced[indice] line
sliced[indice] is equal to ' line ', identical to ' line ' item.
scat is equal to ' 12 '.
indice =  4
sliced[indice] like
indice =  5
sliced[indice] sparkling
indice =  6
sliced[indice] wine
indice =  7
sliced[indice] Line  <-- *WHY IS THIS NOT CONSIDERED EQUAL TO "line"?*
indice =  8
sliced[indice] up
indice =  9
sliced[indice] now
indice =  10
sliced[indice] behind
indice =  11
sliced[indice] the
indice =  12
sliced[indice] cow
scat exdented:  12
frequence:  1
podium:  [1, 1, 1, 1]
'''
```

AND HERE IS MY QUESTION:

The item "`line`" is represented 2 times in the list and I was sure that `scat=11` and `frequence = 2`.

I've tried many different indentations, but the principal interest is that I have a lack of capacity to follow the course of the operations that the program commands to the machine.

To illustrate this I tried to print many steps, but I could really use some further clarification. Please help.

Comment: @logic. Thanks so much for the styllistical modification . As you guess, reading english an writing are not easy for me but I like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python string comparisons are case sensitive.  so `'A' == 'a'` is `False`.  If you want to do case-insensitive comparisons, you should user the `lower` or `upper` methods to make the strings lower or uppercase.  So `'A'.lower() == 'a'` is `True`.

In your case, since they are multi-character strings, you would want to use lower on both, such as `sliced[indice].lower() == item.lower()`.  You could also convert the whole list to lowercase before you start, avoiding the problem entirely, like so:

```
slicedlow = [item.lower() for item in sliced]
```

However, you could convert the whole algorithm to a couple of lines using the `collections.Counter` object:

```
from collections import Counter
slicedlow = [item.lower() for item in sliced]
counts = Counter(slicedlow)
maxcount = max(counts.values())
```

Or even a one-liner:

```
from collections import Counter
maxcount = max(Counter(item.lower() for item in sliced).values())
```

Comment: Yes! I ame inattentive and inadvertent. How many time for this...@TheBlackCat: Thank's

Comment: If this is the correct answer, please mark it as such so others can find it.